# is there any way to add custom extra infomation on ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: java, android, android-intent, action-open-document-tree

I have to ask the user for the name of the folder where a file is to be saved.
I also have to send information related to the name of the file that is supposed to be saved.
Is there any way to send this information along with the intent?
If I do this:

```
  Intent originalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
  originalIntent.putExtra("extra",blabla);
  originalIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.choose_dir));
  startActivityForResult(originalIntent, REQUEST_CHOOSE_DIR);
```

in onActivityResult I cannot see any extra information

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
 if(data.getExtras() != null)
 {
 //do stuff here
 }
}
```

data.getExtras is always null

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to send this information along with the intent?

If you mean "send this information along, such that I will get it back in `onActivityResult()`", then no. You need to hold onto that data in whatever is making the request (activity, fragment, etc.), or in something associated with it (e.g., viewmodel).